# I tried to create an django hello world program then I got this error

Tags: django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('love/', include('love.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I tried this code by seeing n online documentation and I see the code as same as the one in the documentation but I see the error and I can not start practicing django.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('love/', include('love.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in ad.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^love/
^admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

It is being shown on the web

Comment: As the error refers, you need to use either ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/love/``` or ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/```.

Comment: You have not defined the "" url (which means http://127.0.0.1:8000/) but you have defined only '/love' (which means http://127.0.0.1:8000/love) and '/admin' (which means http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin). Try to access the last two. If you want to access a home page define a url for it by "path('',include('home.urls'))" and define the home.url file contents. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must define empty path to use 127.0.0.1:8000

```
path('', include('love.urls')),
```

Comment: @SaiAkshayErupaka: You should mark the answer as correct if it worked for you so that the question is no longer shown as unanswered.